# Is it customary to be reimbursed for travel to a PhD interview day?

Tags: interview, travel

I'm applying for PhD programmes over in the UK and begun to get my first invitations for interviews. Some of them have to be in person as they include a tour of the facilities and such. Unfortunately, travel over here is not cheap and it got me wondering - **is it customary for the interviewing institution to reimburse the cost of my travel**?

On one hand the invitation emails do not mention anything about the cost of travel but on the other hand I got reimbursed even for travelling to my undergraduate interviews.

Comment: They might, if they have money for it. In some places (i don't know about UK) they can't, unless you dress the whole thing not as an interview but as you being a visiting scientist giving a seminar talk or something.

Comment: You'll need to ask them directly.

Comment: Did your undergraduate interview invites specify that you will be reimbursed?

Answer (score 5):

If the invitation did not specify that you'll be reimbursed, then assume that you won't.

Comment: +1, I've had recent experience of such interviews and this is exactly what happens.

Comment: But it is legitimate to ask whether travel will be reimbursed.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth It is legitimate to ask.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said :-)

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Sorry, I read that as "but is it..." Whoops! :)

Comment: I figured so :-)